# How to add the same border-radius to element and box-shadows of element

Tags: css

I have an element on which i add two box-shadows and I want the corners of the element AND the box shadows to have the same border-radius. Somehow it's not happening.
The element appears with a different border-radius than the first box-shadow, and the first box-shadow appears with a different border radius than the second box-shadow.

Here's the code:

```
.stack_item{
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 9%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -15px 0px -7px rgb(206, 204, 204), 0px -29px 0px -13px rgb(168, 168, 168);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -15px 0px -7px rgb(206, 204, 204), 0px -29px 0px -13px rgb(168, 168, 168);
  box-shadow: 0px -15px 0px -7px rgb(206, 204, 204), 0px -29px 0px -13px rgb(168, 168, 168);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making your shadow shrink, the border-radius is also shrinking.

Set it on a larger pseudo-element and it will be ok

```css
.stack_item{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

.stack_item:before,
.stack_item:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 50px;
    border-radius: inherit;
}

.stack_item:before {
    left: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0px -8px 0px 0px rgb(206, 204, 204);
    z-index: -1;
}
.stack_item:after {
    left: 13px;
    right: 13px;
    box-shadow:  0px -16px 0px 0px rgb(168, 168, 168);
    z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="stack_item"></div>
```